# angularjs $scope.$apply() gives this error: Error: [$rootScope:inprog]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to update some texts on a page that is part of $scope. But I keep getting this error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] [http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply][1]
at Error (native)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:6:450
at m (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:101:443)
at h.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:108:301)
at h.$scope.changeLang (http://treenovum.es/xlsmedical/js/medical-app.js:80:16)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:169:382
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:186:390
at h.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:108:40)
at h.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:108:318)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:186:372)
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong. :)
Any ideas of how I can fix this? I want the page to update to the new variables in the scope.

This is the code I'm using for updating:

```
medicalApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $cookies, getTranslation) {
    getTranslation.get(function(data){
        $scope.translation = data;
    });

    $scope.changeLang = function (lang) {
        console.log(lang);
        $cookies.lang = lang;
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            getTranslation.get(function(data){
                $scope.translation = data;
                console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.translation));
            });
        });
    };
});
```

the html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    ...
            <div class="header-lang col-xs-4">
                <p>
                    <a href="#" ng-click="changeLang('de')">DE</a> | 
                    <a href="#" ng-click="changeLang('fr')">FR</a></p>
            <div>{{ translation.text }}</div>  <---- Example variable I want updated.
    ...
```

I'm also using ngRoute with separate controllers for each page I load, if that has anything todo with it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are using `$scope.$apply(...)` inside the function `changeLang` so you are getting the common 'already in a digest' error. You don't need to put the call to `getTranslation` inside a $scope.$apply(...) block because `ng-click` already has you taken care of. Yank that out and it should just work. Also, I'd recommend running with a non-minified version of angular for dev so you can see better errors in your console.

Comment: I'm not sure if your solution works or not, but I did realise the problem is something else. getTranslation is a factory which is called when the page is loaded, but when I call it a second time its ignored. Do you happen to know how to solve that?

Comment: I need to see the getTranslation code, but it sounds like you are dealing with the `singleton` lifetime of a service. Remember that angular doles out singleton instances from its Dependency Injection container.

Answer (score 25):

If your template don't change after changing models and you need using `$scope.$apply`, You can use `$scope.$applyAsync` instead of this.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-codemirror/issues/73

Comment: Wonderful! This solved an issue I was having, much obliged!

Answer (score 2):

$evalAsync works great:

```
$scope.$evalAsync(function() {
    // Code here
});
```

Or simply:

```
$scope.$evalAsync();
```

See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$evalAsync