# $scope.$apply returning error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Running into an issue here.  I have an `ng-repeat` on my page which is displaying data coming from my rest api that i've set up.  I have a delete button on each of my products, when I delete, the item actually goes away (and when i refresh I can see that) but I'm trying to have the article delete off the page at the time delete is clicked (without refreshing). I've tried using `$scope.$apply()` as well as following the response from this [Angular JS : $Scope.Apply()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28689467/angular-js-scope-apply) but still no luck.  Using `$scope.$apply()` just gives me an error:

Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example of your issue? There isn't enough information in your question to tell what's happening.

Comment: That error means that the digest cycle is already in progress, and you're trying to kick it off again by calling `$scope.$apply`. As @elclanrs says there simply isn't enough information here to help you, you need to post the code.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, I'm assuming you're removing the item using your service, but not updating the array of items bound to your ng-repeat. You should probably avoid the `$scope.$apply()` unless you're performing actions that would usually be out of sync with the digest cycle.

Comment: Actually, you made me see the light here.  I was definitely removing the items using my service, so all I had to do was re-call my `$http.get` method which gives me an updated object in my DB.  That's exactly what i needed.  Thanks!