# Error: [$rootScope:inprog] in Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, x-editable

There is an X-Editable (autocomplete) input on a page. When I activate it and press whether ArrowDown or ArrowUp on a keyboard to choose a person, the first person appears, but a hint "Choose from list" appears as well and there is an error in a console: http://joxi.ru/DmBlqXXsNjNpwA

**info.js:**

```
updateRefField(data, fieldName, dictionaryName, projectType) {

    if (data !== null && !Number.isInteger(data*1)) {
        return this.$q.resolve('Choose from list');
    }

    return this.ProjectService.updateRefField(data, fieldName, dictionaryName, projectType || this.projectType)
        .then((res) => {
            if ((data === null) && ((fieldName === 'GorManager') || (fieldName === 'Manager')
                || (fieldName === 'Author') || (fieldName === 'ChiefDesigner') || (fieldName === 'ChiefDesignerAssistant'))) {
                var that = this;
                setTimeout(function() {
                    that.$scope.$apply(function() {
                        that.current[fieldName] = null;
                    });
                }, 4);
            }
            return this.$q.resolve(res.message || null);
        });
}
```

**xeditable-autocomplete.js:**

```
onshow: function () {
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(that.editorEl.find('select').getKendoComboBox().input).focus();

            var oldValue = that.scope.$data;
            that.editorEl.find('select').getKendoComboBox().bind('change', function (e) {
                if (this.element.val()) {
                    that.scope.$data = this.dataItem() ? this.dataItem().Id : oldValue;
                } else {
                    that.scope.$data = null;
                }
            });

            that.editorEl.find('select').getKendoComboBox().bind('open', function (e) {
                $('.k-popup').on('click', function (event) {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                });
            });

            that.editorEl.find('select').getKendoComboBox().bind('filtering', function (e) {
                var filter = e.filter;

                if (!filter.value) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }, 4);
    }
```

UPDATE: Solved. Added decision in a comment.

Comment: I've read some posts (https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23128220/angularjs-scope-apply-gives-this-error-error-rootscopeinprog, http://www.codingeek.com/angularjs/angular-js-apply-timeout-digest-evalasync/, http://www.codelord.net/2015/10/14/angular-nitpicking-differences-between-timeout-and-settimeout/, http://www.ngroutes.com/questions/1a02555/scope-function-is-not-defined-anonymous-function.html), but still can't get rid of error.

Comment: there is no concept of `$scope` & `$rootScope` in angular2, I think you are using angular-1.X

Comment: I guess it's ngUpgrade but I don't know about it myself.

Comment: Scopes are in the whole app, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code, that was returning options into select, was like this:

```
read: (options) => {
            EmployeesService.getEmployees(options.data, currentEmployeeId).then((employees) => {
                options.success(employees);
            });
        }
```

I added setTimeout and the code changed to this:

```
read: (options) => {
            EmployeesService.getEmployees(options.data, currentEmployeeId).then((employees) => {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    return options.success(employees);
                }, 4);
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that the `$digest` is already in progress.

Try to change `that.$scope.$apply(function() {` in `that.$scope.$applyAsync(function() {`.